# Eliminating repeating code in python

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I'm trying to create a GUI in with PyQt4, I initially used QT designer to get my overall layout done and then modify the code afterwards. What I have noticed is that there is a lot of repeating code that would be replaced with wither a class or method but I'm not sure which would be better or how exactly to go about implementing either way properly. here is an example of the repeating code (its a very large program)

```
self.ch2_R = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
self.ch2_R.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
self.ch2_R.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
self.ch2_R.setFrame(True)
self.ch2_R.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
self.ch2_R.setReadOnly(True)
self.ch2_R.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ch2_R"))
print self.ch2_R

self.ch3_R = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
self.ch3_R.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
self.ch3_R.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
self.ch3_R.setFrame(True)
self.ch3_R.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
self.ch3_R.setReadOnly(True)
self.ch3_R.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ch3_R"))

self.ch4_R = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
self.ch4_R.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
self.ch4_R.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
self.ch4_R.setFrame(True)
self.ch4_R.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
self.ch4_R.setReadOnly(True)
self.ch4_R.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ch4_R"))

sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.ch2_R.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.ch3_R.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.ch4_R.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ch2_R, 4, 5, 1, 4)
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ch3_R, 5, 5, 1, 4)
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ch4_R, 6, 5, 1, 4)
```

this code is all within

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
        def setupUi(self, Form):
```

My intial attempt was to creaet a method inside the Ui_Form class like this

```
def myQtlineEdit(self, name, form, sizePolicy):
        self.name = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.name.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.name.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.name.setFrame(True)
        self.name.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.name.setReadOnly(True)
        self.name.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("%s" %name))

        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.name.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

self myQtlineEdit("ch2_R", form, sizePolicy)
```

It did create the text field I was looking for but the

```
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ch2_R, 4, 5, 1, 4)
```

would give me an error saying that ch2_R did no exsist

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a attribute named `ch2_R` you are always assigning to attribute `self.name`, you should instead do this

```
def myQtlineEdit(self, name, form, sizePolicy):
    widget = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
    widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    widget.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
    widget.setFrame(True)
    widget.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    widget.setReadOnly(True)
    widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("%s" %name))

    setattr(self, name, widget)

    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
```